# web scraping a table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a table from the url: http://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/9-34647855-C-T

I do the following:

```
library(rvest)
url<-"http://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/variant/9-34647855-C-T"
frq_table <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("#frequency_table") %>% html_table()
```

I got that "#frequency_table" bit by using inspect element in Chrome and 
copying selector corresponding to the table. However the table I get do to contain any values just NAs.

```
    frq_table
[[1]]
              Population Allele Count Allele Number Number of Homozygotes Allele Frequency
1 European (Non-Finnish)           NA            NA                    NA               NA
2      Ashkenazi Jewish*           NA            NA                    NA               NA
3             East Asian           NA            NA                    NA               NA
4                  Other           NA            NA                    NA               NA
5                African           NA            NA                    NA               NA
6                 Latino           NA            NA                    NA               NA
7            South Asian           NA            NA                    NA               NA
8     European (Finnish)           NA            NA                    NA               NA
9                  Total           NA            NA                    NA               NA
```

I must be assigning the wrong path .... can't figure out how to extract the values.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to learn some JavaScript: https://github.com/igvteam/igv.js

Comment: You might be able to use [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html), with either a "real" browser or a virtual one (phantomJS). It allows you to still scrape data from pages "protected/augmented" by javascript data libraries.